# How do I send an email in a shiny app in R?

Tags: r, shiny, sendmailr

I'm trying to send an email from my shiny app using the library mailR. My code is:

```
      send.mail(from,to,subject=subject,body=msg,smtp=
list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com",port=465,user.name="name",passwd='psswd',ssl=TRUE),
authenticate = TRUE, send=TRUE)
```

(from,to,name,password... are not shown for privacy reasons).

When I run this code, I get the following error:

[image: Error mailR]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hello. Do you launch your app on your computer or on a server ?

Comment: @Billy34 Thanks for replying. I'm launching it on a server. Each time I run the app with that code, the server disconnects. When I run it from RStudio I get the error shown.

Answer (score 2):

After many tries I think that the best option is sending emails using "emayili" through a mailgun account

```
library(shiny)
library(emayili)


ui <- fluidPage(

actionButton("buttonId", "Send email")

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

observeEvent(input$buttonId, {
    
    smtp <- emayili::mailgun(
        username = "SMTP username (postmaster@sandbox.......mailgun.org)",
        password = "SMTP password"
    )
    
    emayili <- envelope()
    emayili <- emayili %>%
        from("sender_email") %>%
        to("receiver_email") %>%
        subject("subject here") %>%
        text("text here")
    
    smtp(emayili, verbose = TRUE)

   })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried that library, but I'm not able to make it work in shiny. I get the following error: Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘emayili’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace ‘magrittr’ 1.5 is already loaded, but >= 2.0.1 is required. I tried updating magrittr but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I would try with a clean R installation and reinstall all packages

Comment: Hi Marco. Thanks for the tip. Is it possible to adapt the code so no mailgun account is needed? I would like to use a gmail account or another free alternative.

Comment: Whit gmail account it would work locally but not on the server, see also https://community.rstudio.com/t/shinyapps-io-and-the-sendmailr-package/1719

Comment: And is it possible to use a free alternative to mailgun?

Comment: For what I know mailgun also offers a free plan

Comment: It's just a free trail of one month. I need another solution. Do you think it will work with an alternative?

Comment: No sorry I have no idea if there is any free SMTP email service

Comment: Hi @rEbbasta! I have tried your code using a mailgun account. When I run the last line, I get the following error: Error in `stop_rate_excess()`:
! Request failed after 5 attempts
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
Called from: signal_abort(cnd, .file). Any idea?

Comment: Running rlang::last_trace() to see the error I get: error/purrr_error_rate_excess>
Error in `stop_rate_excess()`:
! Request failed after 5 attempts
---
Backtrace:
    ▆
 1. └─emayili (local) smtp(emayili, verbose = TRUE)
 2.   └─purrr (local) send_mail(...) at emayili/R/server.R:190:4
 3.     └─purrr::rate_sleep(rate, quiet = quiet)
 4.       └─purrr:::stop_rate_excess(rate)
 5.         └─rlang::abort(msg, "purrr_error_rate_excess", rate = rate)